# Spring 3 class suitable for frequent creation and close of database connection

Tags: java, spring

My application has multiple JVMs and each JVM is required to connect to database for inserting process details(like CPU usage, memory stat) at the frequency of 5 minutes.

Total number of JVMs are 40, so I cant keep 40 connection open to database all the time. I want to create connection and then destroy after insert is done (insert does not take more than a second).

My application uses SPRING 3, so my question is there some class in spring framework which can allow to create and destroy connection each time I do insert.

[looked into jdbcTemplate API, also singleDatasource connection factory but doesn't suit requirements]

Answer (score 0):

Handling of resources like Database connections is automatically closed in Frameworks like Spring. But for doing it explicitly you can try

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
```

or close connection manually like

> getDataSource().getConnection().close()

Answer (score 0):

If you only write every five minutes from each JVM, you do not have to use use pools. In that case, `DriverManagerDataSource` javadoc states : *Connection.close() calls will simply close the Connection*, same for `SimpleDriverDataSource`. So simply using Datasources as usual, i.e. closing them when not in use will be Ok.